# encryption and decryption algorithm in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I would like to **encrypt** and **decrypt** one attribute string value of a **model** by using [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) algorithm.

I am wondering in **Rails**, what is the easiest way to have it? Is there any **AES** `gem` library which can be used directly? And how to use it?

Basically I need some guideline on how to apply **[AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)** encryption/decryption in Rails app.

**------- update -------**

I just notice that there is [AES gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/aes). If I add this gem into my GemFile, how can I use it in my application for encryption & decryption?

Answer (score 8):

AFAIK, the `aes` gem wraps the `openssl` Ruby standard library to provide a much more simplified interface. It supports only `aes-256-cbc`, which is 256-bit AES with cipher-block chaining. You would probably add encryption/decryption methods to your models in Rails.

The basic order of operation for encryption would be:

1. compute an AES symmetric encryption key, 256 bits
2. optionally compute an initialization vector for use with `aes-256-cbc` (the `aes` gem can actually do this for you, so you could skip this step)
3. encrypt your message, optionally indicating output `:format` (Base64 by default, otherwise plain Ruby byte-strings) and/or initialization vector `:iv`

That would be:

```
key = AES.key
=> "6476b3f5ec6dcaddb637e9c9654aa687"    # key ends up as a 32-char long hex string

iv = AES.iv(:base_64)
=> "PPDRCMsZhumCdEO1Zm05uw=="

enc64 = AES.encrypt("hello, secret world", key, {:iv => iv})
=> "PPDRCMsZhumCdEO1Zm05uw==$b3CCy/1dAMJ2JG5T50igEMGtvo9Ppkla1c9vrKbo+zQ="
# note that the encrypted result is the :iv 
# and Base64-transformed encrypted message
# concatenated with $
```

You would then decrypt `enc64` by passing in the entire `:iv` + `$` + encrypted message string, as well as the AES 256-bit `key`.

```
AES.decrypt(enc64, key)
=> "hello, secret world"
```

Having had some experience using the `openssl` standard library in Ruby, I can tell you that the documentation in English is sparse, while the Japanese documentation is very good. At any rate, using the `openssl` API is confusing at best, so if you do not mind limiting yourself to `aes-256-cbc`, then this `aes` gem looks to be very helpful.

Mind you, the author does have a caveat with regards to speed. If you find that you require a faster solution, you should have a look at [`FastAES`](https://github.com/nateware/fast-aes). `FastAES` is a C-extension, however, and will require a compiler for your target platform.

Answer (score 7):

Make a module in your app and include this where you want to call the module method:

1. You can create a file **encrytion_algo.rb** under ***lib*** folder of rails project
2. Inside ***config/application.rb*** add `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)`

***encrytion_algo.rb***

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

module EncrytionAlgo
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend self
  end

  def cipher
    OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('aes-256-cbc')  # ('aes-256-cbc')
  end

  def cipher_key
    'jabcderfghfhfddd!'
  end

  def decrypt(value)
    c = cipher.decrypt
    c.key = Digest::SHA256.digest(cipher_key)
    c.update(Base64.decode64(value.to_s)) + c.final
  end

  def encrypt(value)
    c = cipher.encrypt
    c.key = Digest::SHA256.digest(cipher_key)
    Base64.encode64(c.update(value.to_s) + c.final)
  end
end
```

3. Inside `ApplicationController` include above file  `include MyModule`
4. Now you can use `encrypt` and `decrypt` method from any controller:

   `encrypt("This is a text")`

   ==> "h0RGuW5m3Wk9AAspik9ZXVysOcy2IeQrhQDn85mdo5I=%0A"

   `decrypt("h0RGuW5m3Wk9AAspik9ZXVysOcy2IeQrhQDn85mdo5I=%0A")`

   ==> "This is a text"

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled the same problem and created a simple model concern (rails 5) for that:

````
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

module EncryptableModelConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_save :encrypt_encryptable_attributes
    after_save :decrypt_encryptable_attributes
    after_find :decrypt_encryptable_attributes
  end

  module ClassMethods
    # Sets the model `@encryptable_attributes` class instance variable.
    # Encryptable attributes are encrypted before saving using `before_save` hook and decrypted using `after_save` and `after_find` hooks.
    # Example:
    # ```
    #   class Board < BaseModel
    #     encryptable_attributes :name, :title, :content
    #   end
    # ```
    def encryptable_attributes(*attrs)
      @encryptable_attributes = attrs
    end

  end

  # Returns the model's `@encryptable_attributes` class instance variable.
  #
  def encryptable_attributes
    self.class.instance_variable_get(:@encryptable_attributes) || []
  end


  # Encryptes the model's encryptable attributes before saving using Rails' `before_save` hook.
  #
  # **Note: Be careful in calling this method manually as it can corrupt the data.**
  def encrypt_encryptable_attributes
    encryptable_attributes.each do |k|
      self[k] = encrypt(self[k])
    end
  end

  # Decrypts the model's encryptable attributes using Rails' `after_save` and `after_find` hooks.
  #
  # **Note: Be careful in calling this method manually as it can corrupt the data.**
  def decrypt_encryptable_attributes
    encryptable_attributes.each do |k|
      self[k] = decrypt(self[k])
    end
  end

  private

    def cipher
      OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('aes-256-cbc')
    end

    def cipher_key
      Rails.configuration.crypto['key'] # <-- your own key generator here
    end

    def encrypt(value)
      c = cipher.encrypt
      c.key = Digest::SHA256.digest(cipher_key)
      c.iv = iv = c.random_iv
      Base64.encode64(iv) + Base64.encode64(c.update(value.to_s) + c.final)
    end

    def decrypt(value)
      c = cipher.decrypt
      c.key = Digest::SHA256.digest(cipher_key)
      c.iv = Base64.decode64 value.slice!(0,25)
      c.update(Base64.decode64(value.to_s)) + c.final
    end

end
````

Include it in your model you wish to have encryptable attributes

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  include EncryptableModelConcern
  encryptable_attributes :title, :content
end
```

Now, your model attributes will be encrypted on `before_save` and will be decrypted on `after_save` and on `after_find` hooks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use OpenSSL library. Create the following functions and then you can use the encryption and decryption methods.

```
def aes(m,k,t)
  (aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('aes-256-cbc').send(m)).key = Digest::SHA256.digest(k)
  aes.update(t) << aes.final
end

def encrypt(key, text)
  aes(:encrypt, key, text)
end

def decrypt(key, text)
  aes(:decrypt, key, text)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/shuber/attr_encrypted

http://ezcrypto.rubyforge.org/

attr_encrypted works well for me - although I've also used Ezcrypto. It acts as a wrapper around the OpenSSL library.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.