# Encryption algorithm for .Net and Ruby on Rails

Tags: .net, ruby-on-rails, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I will be sending a session token from a .Net MVC app to a RubyOnRails app.  I would like to symmetrically encrypt the token.

Is there a reliable algorithm which will work between the two different languages/frameworks?

My initial thoughts was to use AES.

Comment: What do you mean by *reliable*?

Comment: I mean something that will work between the two languages.

Answer (score 0):

AES is supported in both .NET and Ruby on Rails (see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489486/encryption-and-decryption-algorithm-in-rails) for some RoR caveats).

AES is also well-regarded as a strong symmetric cipher, so it isn't a bad choice to make. Of course, you must ensure both frameworks support the exact mode of operation and padding you require, which will depend upon your security goals.